# How to publish sim time at desired frequency

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to run the simulated time at frequency of 1Hz by publishing to the `/clock` topic and set rosparam `/use_sim_time` to be true/1.

However my following code produce simulated clock at a frequency of few kHz.

If use the commented part, the simulated clock will start at 0 and stops there.

If rosparam `/use_sim_time` is not set or set to false, the commented part will work fine. I am guessing that this clock topic is treated as a usual topic published and the `rospy.Rate` refers back and use the wall time to time the `Rate` object?

```
rospy.init_node('tmp')
pub = rospy.Publisher('/clock', Clock, queue_size=1)
epoch = rospy.Time(1546300800, 0)
rate = rospy.Rate(1)
clock = rospy.Time()
clock.set(1546300800,0)
rate = rospy.Rate(1)


while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.loginfo('')
    epoch += rospy.Duration(1)
    pub.publish(epoch)
    # rate.sleep()
    # rospy.sleep(1)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317294/how-to-publish-sim-time-at-desired-frequency/) by [yk6](https://answers.ros.org/users/40299/yk6/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use python's time module to control the frequency

by adding `import time` and add `time.sleep(1.0)` in the while loop

---

Originally posted by [yk6](https://answers.ros.org/users/40299/yk6/) with karma: 16 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0